# Set default value of a column to another column's value in CREATE statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In creating a new table, how do I set the default value of a column to another column's value from the same table?

so for example:

```
CREATE TABLE app_version
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  version_name character varying(50),
  version_number numeric
)
```

I want `version_name` to be `version_number` if no name was provided.

Can I do `version_name character varying(50) default version_number`?

Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks

*I can't seem to find anything about this on the forums, it's always on INSERT or UPDATE.*

Comment: Can you expand on this line *default value of a column to another column's value*

Comment: You cannot do this with a `default` clause.  You would need a trigger.

Comment: @Prdp I updated the question

Comment: Okay thanks @GordonLinoff, I guess this is the answer then.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the answer to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html) is quite clear that the default value cannot refer to other columns:

> DEFAULT default_expr
>
> The `DEFAULT` clause assigns a default data value for the column whose
>   column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free
>   expression (subqueries and cross-references to other columns in the
>   current table are not allowed). The data type of the default
>   expression must match the data type of the column.
>
> The default expression will be used in any insert operation that does
>   not specify a value for the column. If there is no default for a
>   column, then the default is null.

Hence, you cannot do what you want with a `DEFAULT` clause.